loginpopup window is closing automatically after user authentication for the react web application configured using MSAL and azure
I have created a web application in azure and tried to configure sso  using MSAL react library. But while clicking on the sso button it is redirecting and within seconds it is coming back to the login page.
I have created the following files:
Authconfig.js
export const msalConfig = {auth: {clientId: "client-id",authority: "\`\`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id\`\`",redirectUri: "\`\`http://localhost:5173/home\`\`",},cache: {cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // Use sessionStorage to avoid localStorage issuesstoreAuthStateInCookie: false,},};

LoginButon.js
import React from 'react';import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

const LoginButton = () =\> {const { instance } = useMsal();

const handleLogin = () =\> {instance.loginPopup().catch(e =\> {console.error(e);});};

return (\<button onClick={handleLogin} style={styles.button}\>Sign in with SSO\</button\>);};

const styles = {button: {padding: "10px 20px",backgroundColor: "#0078d4",color: "white",border: "none",borderRadius: "5px",cursor: "pointer",},};

export default LoginButton;

App.js
import React from 'react';import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';import LoginButton from './components/LoginButton';import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {return (\<Router\>\<Routes\>\<Route path="/" element={\<LoginButton /\>} /\>\<Route path="/home" element={\<Home /\>} /\>\</Routes\>\</Router\>);}

export default App;

index.js
// src/index.jsimport React from 'react';import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';import App from './App';import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';

// src/index.jsconst msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise().then(response =\> {if (response) {console.log('User successfully logged in');}}).catch(err =\> {console.error(err);});

ReactDOM.render(\<MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}\>\<App /\>\</MsalProvider\>,document.getElementById('root'));

Home.js
// src/pages/Home.jsimport React from 'react';

const Home = () =\> {return (\<div\>

export default Home;

After clicking on SSO button it needs to validate the user and needs to redirect to Home.js pageAzure:
I have configured http://localhost:5173/home as redirectUri in azure . Also i have added the scopes openid,email and profile

What is the point of the double backticks you appear to be putting around values in your msalConfig object?

The Error your facing is because of misconfiguration of redirect URL in Azure App Registration.
The Redirect URL defined in authConfig and Azure App Registration URL Should be same as shown below.
Azure App Registration -> Authentication ->Single-Page application -> Add URI -> Save.

authConfig.js:
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "<client_ID>", 
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>", 
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/home",
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", 
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, 
    },
  };
  export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", "profile", "email"],
  };  

Below Is complete code for to configure sso using MSAL react library.
LoginButton:
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { loginRequest } from '../authConfig';
const LoginButton = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const handleLogin = () => {
    instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
  };
  return (
    <button onClick={handleLogin} style={styles.button}>
      Sign in with SSO
    </button>
  );
};
const styles = {
  button: {
    padding: "10px 20px",
    backgroundColor: "#0078d4",
    color: "white",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
};
export default LoginButton;

index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import App from './App';
import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const handleRedirect = async () => {
  try {
    await msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Login error:', error);
  }
};
handleRedirect().then(() => {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
  root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <App />
      </MsalProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
});

App.js:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginButton from './components/LoginButton';
import Home from './components/Home';
function App() {
  const { instance, inProgress } = useMsal();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRedirect = async () => {
      if (inProgress === "none") {
        try {
          const response = await instance.handleRedirectPromise();
          if (response) {
            console.log('User successfully logged in:', response);
            navigate('/home');
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Login error:', err);
        }
      }
    };
    handleRedirect();
  }, [instance, navigate, inProgress]);
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<LoginButton />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
export default App;

Home.js:
import React from 'react';
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the Home Page!</h1>
      <p>You are successfully logged in.</p>
     
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;

After Successfully running, I got below page.
Output:



My Application is not a single page application its a web application  and i m using the same redirect URI configured in my authconfig also

Now i have configured my  application as single page application and have configured the redirect uri as same but still the issue is there

@Airin Anil You need to use Single page application for react app, that is reason it is coming back to the login page again.

Now i have configured my application as single page application and have configured the redirect uri as same but still the issue is there

@Airin Anil Did you delete the web application URL?

Yes i have deleted it already

@Airin Anil After Changing the URL, restart the App.

@Airin Anil Have you checked my code?

Yes i m using your same code

Which token we have to select for authorization endpoint.
Access token or ID tokens?

@Airin Anil Select ID Token.

Could you please check  this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78971008/after-clicking-in-sso-button-i-wanted-to-redirect-to-home-page-after-successfu
