After clicking in sso button ,i wanted to redirect to /home page after successfully authenticating the user
I have created a web application in azure and tried to configure sso using MSAL react library. But while clicking on the sso button it is not redirecting to /home page and also the token generation is also not hapening.
Authconfig.js
export const msalConfig = {auth: {clientId: "client-id",authority: "\`\`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id\`\`",redirectUri: "\`\`http://localhost:5173/home\`\`",},cache: {cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",  issuesstoreAuthStateInCookie: false,},};

main.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { PricingComponent } from './PricingComponent.jsx';

import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AboutComponent } from './AboutComponent.jsx';
import { AdminComponent } from './AdminComponent.jsx';
import { BuildComponent } from './BuildComponent.jsx';
import { ContactusComponent } from './ContactusComponent.jsx';
import { FeedbackComponent } from './FeedbackComponent.jsx';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './LandingPageComponent.jsx';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './LoginPageComponent.jsx';
import { ReleasenotesComponent } from './ReleasenotesComponent.jsx';
import { UserHomeComponent } from './UserHomeComponent.jsx';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './UserProfileComponent.jsx';
import './index.css';
import { ProtectedRoutes } from './utils/ProtectedRoutes.jsx';


const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
  path:'/',
  element: <LandingPageComponent />,
  
  errorElement: <div>404 not found</div>,
  children : [
    {
      path: '',
      element: <AboutComponent />,
    },
    {
      path: 'pricing',
      element: <PricingComponent />,
    },
    {
      path: 'releasenotes',
      element: <ReleasenotesComponent /> ,
    },
    
    {
      path: 'contactus',
      element: <ContactusComponent />,
    },
    {
      path: 'signin',
      element: <LoginPageComponent />,
    },
    {
    element: <ProtectedRoutes />,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'home',
      element: <UserHomeComponent />,
    },
    {
      path: 'build',
      element: <BuildComponent />,
    },
    {
      path: 'admin',
      element: <AdminComponent /> ,
    },
    {
      path: 'userprofile',
      element: <UserProfileComponent /> ,
    },
    {
      path: 'feedback',
      element: <FeedbackComponent />,
    },
    ],
    },
    
  ],
},


]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

Loginpagecomponent.jsx

import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import loginimage from './assets/loginimage.svg';
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { loginRequest } from './Authconfig';

export const LoginPageComponent = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const handleLogin = () => {
    instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
    };


    
    return (
        <div className="bg-white">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center m-20">
                <div>
                    <img
                        loading="lazy"
                        src={loginimage}
                        className="self-end max-w-full aspect-square w-[540px]"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col ml-5">
                    <div className="flex flex-col p-10 mt-5 w-fit items-center justify-center rounded-lg shadow-sm bg-sky-600 bg-opacity-20 text-zinc-800 max-md:px-5 max-md:mt-10">
                        <div className="text-4xl font-black text-sky-600">      
                      </div>
                        <button
                            onClick={handleLogin}
                            className="w-96 px-8 py-3 ml-6 rounded-lg bg-indigo-500 text-gray-100 border border-gray-200 placeholder-gray-500 text-sm tracking-wide font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-700 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out flex items-center justify-center focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none mt-5"
                        >
                            <svg className="w-6 h-6 -ml-2" fill="none" stroke="currentColor">
                                <path d="M16 21v-2a4 4 0 00-4-4H5a4 4 0 00-4 4v2" />
                                <circle cx="8.5" cy="7" r="4" />
                                <path d="M20 8v6M23 11h-6" />
                            </svg>
                            <span className="ml-3">Login With SSO</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

UserHomeComponent.jsx

import React, { PureComponent, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineExclamationCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { CiCircleRemove } from "react-icons/ci";
import { FaRegCircleCheck } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { PiClockCountdown } from "react-icons/pi";
import { Area, AreaChart, Bar, BarChart, Cell, Label, Pie, PieChart, Rectangle, ResponsiveContainer, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis } from 'recharts';
import bannerlogo from './assets/buildnowlogo.svg';
import { AuthContext } from './utils/AuthContext';

export const UserHomeComponent = () => {

  const [orgdata, setOrgData] = useState([]);
  const [responsedata,setResponsedata] = useState([]);
  const [responsedata2,setResponsedata2] = useState([]);
  const [responsedata3,setResponsedata3] = useState([]);
  const [changefailrate,setChangeFailRate] = useState([]);
  const [failurejobs,setFailurejobs] =useState([]);
  const [successjobs,setSuccessjobs] =useState([]);
  const [unstablejobs,setUnstablejobs] =useState([]);
  const [avgleadtime,setAvgleadtime] =useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [queryDate, setQueryDate] = useState('30');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [postdata,setPostData] = useState({orgname: "", days: "" , projectbasename:""});
  const [ischange, setIsChange] = useState(false);
  const [visibleTooltip, setVisibleTooltip] = useState(null);
  const baseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL;
  const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
  const cx = 120;
  const cy = 100;
  const iR = 60;
  const oR = 100;
  const percentage = changefailrate.Percentage
  const color = '#d0d000';

  const isAdm = user.isServiceAdmin
  const userid=user.userinfo.sAMAccountName
  const memberrole=user.memberRoles
  
  
  const handleSelectionChange = (e) => {
  
    const [ofr, spr] = e.target.value.split(' ');
    setPostData({orgname:ofr,days:queryDate,projectbasename:spr});
    
    setIsChange(true);
    
    };


const fetchOrgData = async () => {

  const userdetail = {
    username: userid,
    isServiceAdmin: isAdm,
    memberRoles:memberrole
  };
    const response= await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowJenkins/getMultiBranch`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userdetail),
      });
    const result =await response.json();
    
    
      setOrgData(result);
      setPostData({orgname:result.multiBranchInfo[0].OrgFolder,days:queryDate,projectbasename:result.multiBranchInfo[0].MultiBranchProject});
      setIsChange(true);
  };



  const handledateChange  = (e) => {
    const dat = e.target.value;
    setQueryDate(dat);
    postdata.days = dat
    setIsChange(true);
    
  
  };


  const filteredList = (orgdata.multiBranchInfo || []).filter((item) =>
    `${item.OrgFolder} ${item.MultiBranchProject}`
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );


useEffect(() => {
  
  fetchOrgData();

  }
, []);


    
const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
  setSearchTerm(e.target.value);

};

const fetchfailurejobs =async() => {
  setIsLoading(true);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowdorametrics/projectfailurejobs/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
    const responsedata = await response.json();
    setFailurejobs(responsedata)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  } finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  } 
};

const fetchsuccessjobs =async() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowdorametrics/projectsuccessjobs/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
    const responsedata = await response.json();
    setSuccessjobs(responsedata)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  } finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};

const fetchunstablejobs =async() => {
  setIsLoading(true);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowdorametrics/projectunstablejobs/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
    const responsedata = await response.json();
    setUnstablejobs(responsedata)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  } finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};

const fetchaverageleadtime =async() => {
  setIsLoading(true);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowdorametrics/projectaverageleadtime/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
    const responsedata = await response.json();
    setAvgleadtime(responsedata)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  } finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};


const projectleadtime = async () => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowdorametrics/projectleadtime/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
  
    const responsedata = await response.json();
    setResponsedata2(responsedata)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  } finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
  
};

const projectdeploymentfrequencydaywise = async () => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowdorametrics/projectdeploymentfrequencydaywise/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
  
    const responsedata = await response.json();
    setResponsedata(responsedata)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    
  } finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
  
};


const projectdeployment = async() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowdorametrics/projectdeployment/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
  
    const responsedata = await response.json();
    setResponsedata3(responsedata)
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  } finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};

const changefailurerate = async() => {
    
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/buildNowAdm/buildnowadminmetrcs/changefailurerate/`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    });
  
    const rd = await response.json();
    setChangeFailRate(rd)
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
};

const LoadingComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div class="border w-96 h-44 border-gray-100 ">
    <div class="animate-pulse flex">
        <div class=" flex space-x-4 items-end relative ml-20">
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-16"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-24"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-16"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-20"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-8"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-20"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-24"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-36"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-20"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-16"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-24"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-16"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-20"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-8"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-20"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-24"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-36"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-20"></div>
        <div class="w-4 bg-slate-200 rounded h-32"></div>
        </div>
      
    
    </div>
  </div>
  )
};


class CustomizedLabel extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { x, y, value } = this.props;

    return (
      <text x={x} y={y} dy={-4}  fontSize={10} textAnchor="middle">
        {value}
      </text>
    );
  }
}


const needle = (percentage, cx, cy, iR, oR, color) => {
  const ang = 180.0 * (1 - percentage / 100); // calculate angle based on percentage
  const length = (iR + 2 * oR) / 3;
  const sin = Math.sin(-RADIAN * ang);
  const cos = Math.cos(-RADIAN * ang);
  const r = 5;
  const x0 = cx + 5;
  const y0 = cy + 5;
  const xba = x0 + r * sin;
  const yba = y0 - r * cos;
  const xbb = x0 - r * sin;
  const ybb = y0 + r * cos;
  const xp = x0 + length * cos;
  const yp = y0 + length * sin;

  return [
    <circle key="circle" cx={x0} cy={y0} r={r} fill={color} stroke="none" />,
    <path key="path" d={`M${xba} ${yba}L${xbb} ${ybb} L${xp} ${yp} L${xba} ${yba}`} stroke="none" fill={color} />,
  ];
};

if (ischange===true)
  {
  console.log(postdata);
  changefailurerate();
  projectdeployment();
  fetchsuccessjobs();
  fetchfailurejobs();
  fetchunstablejobs();
  fetchaverageleadtime();
  projectleadtime();
  projectdeploymentfrequencydaywise();
  setIsChange(false);
  };


  return (
    <>
    {
      user.memberRoles.length === 0 ? (
        <div className=' grid justify-center items-center h-[90%]  bg-slate-100 '>
          <div className=' shadow-md p-10 bg-slate-200 m-20'>
          <div className='flex items-center justify-center mb-10'>
          <img src={bannerlogo} />
          <h5 className='text-6xl text-center font-extrabold text-sky-700 ml-5'>buildNow</h5>
          
          </div>
          <h5 className='text-3xl text-center  text-slate-400 mb-5'>oops!...</h5>  
          <p className='text-center text-slate-700 text-2xl font-normal'>
          Your <span className='font-bold'> projects haven't been </span> migrated yet or your <span className='font-bold'>users haven't been assigned to the</span> IdM2BCD <span className='font-bold'>role</span>. <br/>
          Contact the <span className='font-bold'>buildNow team</span> for assistance.
          </p>
          </div>
        </div> ) : (
    <>
    <div className="justify-center items-center text-center p-2 mt-5 w-full text-2xl font-bold leading-9 text-sky-600 rounded-xl border border-black border-solid bg-zinc-900 max-md:px-5 max-md:max-w-full">
        DORA+ METRICS
    </div>

    <div className="grid grid-flow-col text-sky-800 font-bold justify-center items-center gap-10 mt-2 p-1">
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search Project..."
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleSearchChange}
        className='w-96'
      />
      <div>
      <select className='w-96'onChange={handleSelectionChange} value={`${postdata.orgname} ${postdata.projectbasename}`} >
      
        {filteredList.map((item) => (
          <option key={item.MultiBranchProject} value={`${item.OrgFolder} ${item.MultiBranchProject}`}>
            {item.OrgFolder} {item.MultiBranchProject}
          </option>
        
        ))}
      
      </select>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div>
      <select  size={1} defaultValue="30" onChange={handledateChange} value={postdata.days}
      className="block w-80 p-3 mt-1  border-b-2 border-gray-400 rounded-sm shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
        <option  value="7" id="daysDropdown">7 days</option>
        <option  value="14" id="daysDropdown">14 days</option>
        <option  value="30" id="daysDropdown">30 days</option>

      </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className=' text-center'>
      {postdata.orgname && postdata.projectbasename && (
        <div >
          <p><span className=' font-semibold ' >Org:</span>  {postdata.orgname},  <span className=' font-semibold' > Project:</span> {postdata.projectbasename}</p>
      </div>
      )}
      </div>

      <div className=' grid grid-cols-12'>
      <div className='col-span-4 sm:gap-2 gap-4 mt-5 justify-center ml-5'>
      <div className=' flex flex-grow gap-2 md:gap-4 '>
      <div className="items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 rounded-xl shadow-sm mb-2">
      <div className='flex flex-auto items-center justify-center'>
      <h5 className="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-900 pe-1">Change Failure Rate</h5> 
      <div className='relative flex items'>
      <AiOutlineExclamationCircle
      size={10}
      onMouseEnter={() => setVisibleTooltip('1')}
      onMouseLeave={() => setVisibleTooltip(null)}
      className="cursor-pointer " />
      {visibleTooltip === '1' && (
        <div className="absolute bottom-full mb-2 w-96 p-2 bg-slate-50 text-sm rounded-md shadow-lg">
          Change failure rate represents the percentage of deployments that result in failures in the production environment. 
  
        </div>
      )}</div>
      </div>
      <div className='w-64 h-32' >
      <ResponsiveContainer >
      <PieChart >
        <Pie
          dataKey="value"
          startAngle={180}
          endAngle={0}
          data={[{ value: 100, color: '#ff1a1a' }]} // single slice to fill the semi-circle
          cx={cx}
          cy={cy}
          innerRadius={iR}
          outerRadius={oR}
          fill="#8884d8"
          stroke="none"
        >
        <Label value={`${percentage}%`}/>
        <Cell fill="#ff4d4d" /> {/* background color */}
        </Pie>
        {needle(percentage, cx, cy, iR, oR, color)}
        
      </PieChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid justify-center w-40 h-40  bg-slate-50  rounded-xl shadow-sm ">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center pb-10 mt-2">
      <div className='flex flex-auto justify-center'>
      <p className="mb-5 text-sm font-semibold font-sans pe-1">Overall Deployment</p>
      <div className='relative flex mt-1'>
      <AiOutlineExclamationCircle
      size={10}
      onMouseEnter={() => setVisibleTooltip('2')}
      onMouseLeave={() => setVisibleTooltip(null)}
      className="cursor-pointer" />
      {visibleTooltip === '2' && (
        <div className="absolute bottom-full mb-2 w-96 p-2 bg-slate-50 text-sm rounded-md shadow-lg">
          The total number of deployments carried out during the given time frame.
        </div>
      )}</div>
      </div>
      <h5 className="mt-3 text-4xl font-medium text-gray-900">{responsedata3.count}</h5>
      <PiClockCountdown  size={50} color="blue" />
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-auto gap-2 md:gap-4 ml-2 mb-5 md:mt-5 lg:mt-10'>
      <div className="grid justify-center w-40 h-40  bg-slate-50  rounded-xl shadow-sm  ">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center pb-10 mt-5">
      <div className='flex flex-auto justify-center'>
      <p className="mb-2 text-md font-semibold font-sans pe-1 ">Success Jobs</p>
      <div className='relative flex mt-1'>
      <AiOutlineExclamationCircle
      size={10}
      onMouseEnter={() => setVisibleTooltip('3')}
      onMouseLeave={() => setVisibleTooltip(null)}
      className="cursor-pointer" />
      {visibleTooltip === '3' && (
        <div className="absolute bottom-full mb-2 w-96 p-2 bg-slate-50 text-sm rounded-md shadow-lg">
          The total number of builds that were completed successfully during the specified time period.
        </div>
      )}</div>
      </div>
      <h5 className="mb-2 text-4xl font-medium text-gray-900">{successjobs.count}</h5>
      <FaRegCircleCheck   size={50} color="#00b300" />
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid justify-center w-40 h-40  bg-slate-50   rounded-xl shadow-sm  ">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center pb-10 mt-5">
      <div className='flex flex-auto justify-center'>
      <p className="mb-2 text-md font-semibold font-sans pe-1">Failure Jobs</p>
      <div className='relative flex mt-1'>
      <AiOutlineExclamationCircle
      size={10}
      onMouseEnter={() => setVisibleTooltip('4')}
      onMouseLeave={() => setVisibleTooltip(null)}
      className="cursor-pointer" />
      {visibleTooltip === '4' && (
        <div className="absolute left-full mb-2 w-96 p-2 bg-slate-50 text-sm rounded-md shadow-lg">
          The total number of builds that failed during the specified time period
        </div>
      )}</div>
      </div>
      <h5 className="mb-2 text-4xl font-medium text-gray-900">{failurejobs.count}</h5>
      <CiCircleRemove  size={50} color="#ff4d4d" />
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid justify-center w-40 h-40 bg-slate-50  rounded-xl shadow-sm ">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center pb-10 mt-5">
      <div className='flex flex-auto justify-center'>
      <p className="mb-2 text-md font-semibold font-sans pe-1">Unstable Jobs</p>
      <div className='relative flex mt-1'>
      <AiOutlineExclamationCircle
      size={10}
      onMouseEnter={() => setVisibleTooltip('5')}
      onMouseLeave={() => setVisibleTooltip(null)}
      className="cursor-pointer" />
      {visibleTooltip === '5' && (
        <div className="absolute left-full mb-2 w-64 p-2 bg-slate-50 text-sm rounded-md shadow-lg">
          The total number of Unstable builds carried out during the given time frame.
        </div>
      )}</div>
      </div>
      <h5 className="mb-2 text-4xl font-medium text-gray-900">{unstablejobs.count}</h5>
      <AiOutlineExclamationCircle  size={50} color="#ff8000" />
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

    
      <div className="col-span-8 mt-5 gap-4 m-2 justify-center ">
      <div className=" items-center justify-center bg-gray-50  rounded-xl shadow-sm mb-1 md:mb-5 lg:mb-15 ">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
        { avgleadtime.AverageLeadTime && (
        <div class="text-left text-xs">
            Avg Lead Time<span className='text-2xl font-medium'>({avgleadtime.AverageLeadTime})</span>
        </div>)}
        <div class="mx-auto text-xl font-semibold relative flex">
        Lead Time
        <AiOutlineExclamationCircle
        size={10}
        onMouseEnter={() => setVisibleTooltip('6')}
        onMouseLeave={() => setVisibleTooltip(null)}
        className="  cursor-pointer ml-1 mt-2" />
        {visibleTooltip === '6' && (
          <div className="absolute bottom-full mb-2 w-96 p-2 bg-slate-50 text-sm font-normal rounded-md shadow-lg">
            Lead time for changes is the amount of time it takes a code change to get into production.
            This metric enables businesses to quantify the speed of code delivery to customers or stakeholders.
          </div>
          )}
        </div>
        </div>
      
        {isLoading ? <LoadingComponent /> : responsedata.length === 0 ? (
        <div className="h-44 text-center items-center justify-center pt-10 text-gray-300 font-extrabold text-2xl">Metrics not available for selected time period</div>
        ) : (
        <div className='w-full h-full'>
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={200}>
        <BarChart
        data={responsedata2}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
          }}
        >
          <XAxis dataKey="time">
            <Label value="Date" offset={-5} position="insideBottom" />
            </XAxis>
          <YAxis>
          <Label value="Lead Time(mins)"  angle={-90} position="insideLeft" style={{ textAnchor: 'middle' }}  />
          </YAxis>
          <Tooltip dataKey="time" />
          
          <Bar dataKey="last" fill="#3366ff" activeBar={<Rectangle fill="purple"   />} />
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
      
      </div>)
      }
      </div>
    
      <div className="  items-center justify-center  bg-gray-50  rounded-xl shadow-sm ">
      <div className='flex flex-auto justify-center'> 
      <h5 className="text-xl font-semibold leading-none text-center justify-center text-gray-900 pe-1">Deployment Frequency Day Wise</h5>
      <div className='relative flex mt-1'>
      <AiOutlineExclamationCircle
        size={10}
        onMouseEnter={() => setVisibleTooltip('7')}
        onMouseLeave={() => setVisibleTooltip(null)}
        className="  cursor-pointer" />
        {visibleTooltip === '7' && (
          <div className="absolute bottom-full mb-2 w-96 p-2 bg-slate-50 text-sm rounded-md shadow-lg">
            Day wise deployments carried out during the given time frame
          </div>
          )}</div>
          </div>
      {isLoading ? (<LoadingComponent />) : responsedata.length === 0 ? (
      <div className="h-44 text-center items-center justify-center pt-20 text-gray-300 font-extrabold text-2xl">Metrics not available for selected time period</div>
      ) : (
      <div>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={200}>
        <AreaChart
        data={responsedata}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
          }}
        >
          <XAxis dataKey = "time" >
            <Label value="Date" offset={-5} position="insideBottom"  />
          </XAxis>
          <YAxis>
          <Label value="count"  angle={-90} position="insideLeft" style={{ textAnchor: 'middle' }}  />
          </YAxis>
          <Tooltip />
          
          <Area  dataKey="count" fill="#0040ff"   activeDot={{ r: 3 }}  />
        </AreaChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>)
      }
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </>
      ) 
    }
    </>
  )
}

AuthContext.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
        const storedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
        return storedUser ? JSON.parse(storedUser) : null;
    });

    const login = (userData) => {
        setUser(userData);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userData));
    };

    const logout = () => {
        setUser(null);
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user,setUser,login,logout }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };

ProtectedRoutes.jsx

import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext';

export const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    const { account } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return account ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/signin" />;
};

Landingpagecomponent.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Header } from './Header';
import { AuthProvider } from './utils/AuthContext';

export const LandingPageComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
     
    <AuthProvider>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
    </AuthProvider>
    
    </>
    
  )
}

After clicking on SSO button it needs to validate the user and needs to redirect to Userhomecomponent.jsx page.
I have configured http://localhost:5173/home as redirectUri in azure . Also i have added the scopes openid,email and profile.I have enabled access token and id token also

You can use the Uri best practices to correctly authenticate and redirect to UserHomeComponent.jsx, the documentation suggests that you can use HTTPS and HTTP schemas for the redirect Uri.
Note: HTTP: The HTTP scheme (http://) is supported only for localhost URIs and should be used only during active local application development and testing.
The note suggests that your schema is partially correct http://localhost:5173/home, so if you are using Windows try adding the IPv4 that directs to localhost (we are assuming your app is running to web or emulator in the same machine), try to get the IPv4 equivalent to your localhost, so this way the production server/dev server will redirected correctly to the UserHome component.
Usually, you can get it with ipconfig command or similar,
More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url#prefer-127001-over-localhost
